# Error 401 Unauthorized (Invalid OAuth Token) during AppEngine Deployment with Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, deployment, oauth, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to deploy a fairly large app over an unfortunately fairly slow internet connection from within Eclipse. After something like 15-30 minutes during the file-upload, the deploy process aborts with a 401 Unauthorized (Invalid OAuth Token) error. Is this a timeout on some login-cookie, or am I doing something else wrong?

Workaround:
Luckily AppEngine is smart enough to not re-upload identical files, so all I need to do is an "appcfg rollback" and try to deploy again. Eventually all files are uploaded and everything is fine. Just really annoying...

Thanks,

Markus

Comment: http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Error_codes Invalid username or password?

Comment: It looks like the access token expires after 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me as well. Multiple failures uploading 3000+ files after I localized & code split my GWT application.

My solution is to define an External Tool to launch appcfg.cmd and upload that way.

```
Run menu | External Tools | External Tools Configurations...
Location: ...\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\bin\appcfg.cmd
Working Directory: ${project_loc}
Arguments: update ./war
```

Comment: I belive you, that it works, but I'm not sure I understand why it makes a difference whether you call appcfg explicitly as an external tool or have the Google plugin call it implicitly via deploy. Does deploy use a different version of appcfg? Or does appcfg not use OAuth tokens if you call it directly?

Comment: I'm also interested in this.  Anyone got any more info please?